# Tikz: The position of a label change step-wise and not in a continuous way

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

Consider the following MEW. I do not understand why the position of the label of i2 change step-wise and not in a continuous way.
With 178-180 I get

[image]

With 175-177 I get

[image]

The first is too low, the second too high... It's an error of mine or a weakness of the system?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,intersections}
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,
  dot/.style 2 args={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#2},name=#1},
  dot2/.style 2 args={circle,inner sep=.6pt,draw=black, fill=white,label={#2},name=#1},
  dot3/.style 2 args={circle,inner sep=.8pt,draw=black, fill=white,label={#2},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

  \draw[help lines,step=1] (-1,-1) grid (10,6);
  \draw [->] (-1,0) -- (10,0) node [below left]  {$x$};
  \draw [->] (0,-1) -- (0,6) node [below left] {$y$};

  \node [dot={p1}{[below=1.5mm]$p_1$}] at (3,1) {};
  \node [dot={p2}{[above right]$p_2$}] at (8,0) {};
  \node [dot={p3}{[above=1mm]$p_3$}] at (3.5,2.5) {};
  \node [dot={p4}{[above right]$p_4$}] at (6,3) {};

  \coordinate (i1) at (intersection of p1--p2 and p3--p4);
  \coordinate (i2) at (intersection of p1--p3 and p2--p4);
  \draw [extended line=0.3cm] (p2) -- (i1) ;
  \draw [extended line=0.3cm] (p2) -- (i2) ;
  \draw [extended line=0.3cm] (p4) -- (i1) ;
  \draw [extended line=0.3cm] (p1) -- (i2) ;
  \draw [thick] (p1) -- (p2);
  \draw [thick] (p2) -- (p4);
  \draw [thick] (p3) -- (p4);
  \draw [thick] (p3) -- (p1);
  \draw [very thick,extended line=0.3cm] (i1) -- (i2) ;
  \coordinate (i3) at (intersection of p2--p3 and i1--i2);
  \coordinate (o) at (intersection of p2--p3 and p1--p4);
  \coordinate (i4) at (intersection of i1--o and p2--p4);
  \coordinate (i5) at (intersection of i2--o and p1--p2);
  \coordinate (i6) at (intersection of i1--o and p1--p3);
  \coordinate (i7) at (intersection of i2--o and p3--p4);
  \draw [very thin,extended line=0.3cm] (p1) -- (p4) ;
  \draw [very thin,extended line=0.3cm] (p2) -- (i3) ;
  \draw [very thin,extended line=0.3cm] (i1) -- (i4) ;
  \draw [very thin,extended line=0.3cm] (i2) -- (i5) ;
  \node[dot2,label={}] at (o) {};
  \node[dot2,label={}] at (i4) {};
  \node[dot2,label={}] at (i5) {};
  \node[dot2,label={}] at (i6) {};
  \node[dot2,label={}] at (i7) {};
  \node[dot3,label={[above]$i_1$}] at (i1) {};
  \node[dot3,label={[label distance=0mm]176.0:$i_2$}] at (i2) {}; % <<<=====
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

Comment: increase the `label distance` to see the effect.

Comment: Note that a label is implemented as a separate node, which would give you more control to do manually.   `\path (i1) node[doct3] ++(150:1em) node{$i_1$};`

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you. Here the checked version of your proposal: `\path (i2) node[dot3] {} ++(160:1.5em) node{$i_2$} ;`

Comment: one plus sign `+` is enough `\path (E) +(-75:2mm) node[scale=.8,blue]{E};`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The behavior you encountered is duly documented in the [TikZ & PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), precisely on page 247 for version 3.1.4b. Relevant quotes:

> 1. The 〈angle〉 is used to determine a position on the border of the main node. (...)
> 2. Then, an anchor point for the label node is computed.  It is determined in such a way that the `label node` will “face away” from the border of the `main node`. (...) For angles between these “major” angles, like 30° or 110°, combined anchors, like  `south west` for 30° or `south east` for 110° , are used. However, for angles close to the major angles, (differing by up to 2° from the major angle), the anchor for the major angle is used. Thus, a label at a border point for 2° will have the anchor `west`, while a label for 3° will have the anchor `south west`, resulting in a “jump” of the anchor. You can set the anchor “by hand” using the `anchor` key or indirect keys like `left`.

So, to achieve precise positioning, either use the suggestion given in comments (like `\path (i2) ++(160:1.5em) node{$i_2$} ;`) or apply what the last quoted sentence says using the `anchor` option, as in

```latex
\node[label={[label distance=0mm, anchor=0] 180:$i_2$}] at (i2) {};
```

or

```latex
\node[label={[label distance=0mm, anchor=357] 177:$i_2$}] at (i2) {};
```

Here, the `177` corresponds to 〈angle〉 in the above quote from the manual and is relative to the empty node created by `\node (...) at (i2) {};` (the default is `above`, i.e., `90`), whereas the `anchor=357` concerns the node created by the `label` option. I kept a difference of 180° between them so that they face each other. Here is the output with:

```latex
\node[label={[label distance=0mm, anchor=345] 165:$i_2$}] at (i2) {};
```

[image: screenshot]

To understand the positioning well, I suggest to try something like this:

```latex
\node[name=aaa, draw,
      label={[draw, label distance=0mm, anchor=345] 165:$i_2$}]
  at (i2) {};
\fill[red] (aaa.165) circle (1pt);
```

[image: screenshot]

This way, the function that maps the angle to the `$i_2$` label is continuous (modulo the limited precision of floating point representation), but as mentioned in the comments, one can make the function even more regular by using the `circle` shape for both nodes:

```latex
\node[name=aaa, circle, draw,
      label={[circle, draw, label distance=0mm, anchor=345] 165:$i_2$}]
  at (i2) {};
\fill[red] (aaa.165) circle (1pt);
```

[image: screenshot]

Note: the `label distance` is followed according to the direction determined by 〈angle〉 in the main node options, not the direction indicated with `anchor` in the `label` option. For some reason I don't know, it seems though that the distance between both anchors of interest is the *double* of that indicated with the `label distance` option:

```latex
\node[name=aaa, circle, draw,
      label={[name=bbb, circle, draw, label distance=8mm, anchor=310] 270:$i_2$}]
  at (i2) {};
\fill[red] (aaa.270) circle (1pt);
\fill[blue] (bbb.310) circle (1pt);
\draw[orange!35, <->] (aaa.270) -- node[right] {$d$} +(0,-16mm);
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: very interesting, thank you

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat judging from the last picture of the answer, intuitively, two objects have to become circles, to achieve smoothness + constant distance by changing angle

Comment: I added some precisions regarding this. We already had the continuity (modulo floating or fixed point representation), so “any position” could already be obtained with the  `rectangle` shape; but it is true that the mapping from angle to label position must be more regular with the `circle` shape for both nodes—which I used in the last code snippet and screenshot.

Comment: very interesting

Answer (score 6):

Too long for a comment.
Continous variation can be seen for higher `label distance`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot3/.style 2 args={circle,inner sep=.8pt,fill=black,label={#2},name=#1},]

  \coordinate (i2) at (0,0);
  \draw[thin,gray] (i2) -- ++(178:105mm);
  \draw[thin,gray] (i2) -- ++(179:105mm);
  \draw[thin,gray] (i2) -- ++(180:105mm);

  \node[dot3,label={[label distance=0mm]178.0:$i_2$}] at (i2) {}; % <<<=====
  \node[dot3,label={[label distance=0mm]179.0:$i_2$}] at (i2) {}; % <<<=====
  \node[dot3,label={[label distance=0mm]180.0:$i_2$}] at (i2) {}; % <<<=====  

  \node[dot3,label={[label distance=50mm,blue]178.0:$i_2$}] at (i2) {}; % <<<=====
  \node[dot3,label={[label distance=50mm,blue]179.0:$i_2$}] at (i2) {}; % <<<=====
  \node[dot3,label={[label distance=50mm,blue]180.0:$i_2$}] at (i2) {}; % <<<=====  

  \node[dot3,label={[label distance=100mm,red]178.0:$i_2$}] at (i2) {}; % <<<=====
  \node[dot3,label={[label distance=100mm,red]179.0:$i_2$}] at (i2) {}; % <<<=====
  \node[dot3,label={[label distance=100mm,red]180.0:$i_2$}] at (i2) {}; % <<<=====

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```